# Mathematica not giving exact answer for Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to find the maximum value of

```
d[x_]:=4-(1/5)x^2-3*Cos[Pi*x/6]
```

For -5 < x < 5. Aside from x=0 which is a local minimum, when I use Solve, I can only get the numerical values of x, or an answer with a bunch of #'s that I don't understand, like so:

```
In[61]:= Solve[d'[x] == 0 && -5 <= x <= 5]

Out[61]= {{x -> 0}, {x -> Root[{5 \[Pi] Sin[(\[Pi] #1)/6] - 
   4 #1 &, -3.6804064036641044765}]}, {x -> Root[{5 \[Pi] Sin[(\[Pi] #1)/6] - 4 #1 &, 3.6804064036641044765}]}}
```

Should I just be trying to use different syntax? Instead, which one?

Comment: You can use `N` to get rid of those funny looking characters. `SetSystemOptions[
  "TypesetOptions" -> "NumericalApproximationForms" -> False];
Solve[d'[x] == 0 && -5 <= x <= 5, x] // N` gives `{{x -> 0.}, {x -> -3.68041}, {x -> 3.68041}}` Mathematica can not find exact answer so used Root object.

Comment: Mathematically is impossible to obtain a symbolic(analytic) solution for transcendental equation.To find maximum value try:`NMaximize[{4 - (1/5)*x^2 - 3*Cos[Pi*x/6], -5 <= x <= 5}, x]`

Comment: For a maximum you also want to include the requirement that the second derivative is negative, i.e., `d''[x] < 0`. That will eliminate the minimum at `x == 0`

Answer (score 3):

```
Solve[{d'[x] == 0, -5 < x < 5}, x, Reals] // N
(*{{x -> 0.}, {x -> -3.68041}, {x -> 3.68041}}*)
```

gives what you're looking for (without bunch of # )